# Error when installing Amazon FireOS platform to Phonegap application

Tags: android, cordova

I've created a Phonegap app and am trying to add Amazon FireOS to the platform list.

```
sudo phonegap platform add amazon-fireos
```

As per [these](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_amazonfireos_index.md.html#Amazon%20Fire%20OS%20Platform%20Guide) instructions, I copied the `avw_interface.jar` to `~/.cordova/lib/commonlibs`.

Running the above command returns:

```
Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.
```

However, both are set.

`echo $ANDROID_HOME` -> `~/Android/Sdk`

`echo $PATH` -> contains `~/Android/Sdk/tools` which is where `android` resides.

Has anyone had a similar problem?

**Edit:**
`android` installs properly, but not `fireos`.
However, running `phonegap build android` gives me the same error.

As an aside, when I was using Phonegap with Sencha Touch, I would build for `android` and run on a kindle, so perhaps the same will work here. Maybe I don't need the FireOS platform.

**Edit 2:**
My `app/www/res/screen` directory contains the following directories:

- android
- bada
- bada-wac
- blackberry
- ios
- tizen
- webos
- windows-phone

I believe these were created when I created my app. However, there's no amazon-fireos here. Seems odd.

**My questions:**

1. Why does android install but not fire os
2. Why does android not build (I suppose the same reason my fire os doesn't install?)
3. Should I use android instead of fireos? Is fireos just optimized for kindle fire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How annoying.
I had to run `sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" phonegap platform add amazon-fireos --save`

Resolved the issue with android as well.